# Are Ubuntu CDs still available?

Tags: system-installation, live-cd, canonical

As we celebrate the 12th birthday of Ubuntu, I look back on [the announcement](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2004-October/000003.html) of 4.10 Warty Warthog, and see that back then, in 2004 (***woah***), the only way to get Ubuntu was by CD, and that you could request one [here](http://shipit.ubuntulinux.org/), but now unfortunately, that specific site no longer exists, and [UbuntuLinux.org](http://www.ubuntulinux.org/download/) now redirects to [Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com).

So much has happened since, and so many Ubuntu versions (LTS & not) have been published, eventually CD/DVD support would have to end, but that's a seperate question. I know that CDs are probably out of date, but it's a flash to the past to think about it. So are there still CDs made? If not, when ***DID*** CD support end?

Comment: This is better suited to be pasted on the main Ask Ubuntu site, as it's about Ubuntu, and not about Ask Ubuntu.  :)  (Migrated)

Comment: Seems almost the same to me @ThomasWard though I see the concern, things are very different now, perhaps it is time for a new question on this topic.

Comment: @MarkKirby just a personal opinion that they're *similar* but different.  Ultimately the community at large is correct, so don't interpret me as saying it definitely is not a duplicate.  :)

Comment: @ThomasWard I changed the vote anyway, I do see how this can be different and the answers are out dated there, this would be good for anyone who wants to find a dvd now, I am more than happy to remove the vote.

Comment: @MarkKirby Yeah, looking at it, it's good to get some fresh answers, that question is outdated, 2011

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Not even logically equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

The official program of shipping free CDs is *long* since dead.  Those links are obsolete, as the ShipIt program was [discontinued in 2011 with 11.04](http://blog.canonical.com/2011/04/05/shipit-comes-to-an-end/).

There used to be CDs on the Canonical / Ubuntu store, but it seems like they only provide a [Bootable USB Stick category](https://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17) now, and currently only provide 16.04 sticks.

There are third-party companies [such as OSDisk.com which sell and ship Ubuntu CDs/DVDs, and software repository DVD sets](https://www.osdisc.com/products/linux/ubuntu), but they are not free.  OSDisk at least do appear to do worldwide shipping, but I don't think it's free unless you're buying $20 or more of disks.

So, your only options are to purchase USB media from Canonical, or purchase CDs from a third-party provider, or to download Ubuntu and create the installation media yourself.  (There are no more "Official CD/DVDs" anymore)